# Angular2 material md-input type="date" not working in IE 11

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am using angular2 material in my angular 2 app .The below code working fine in google chrome but not in IE 11. I was thinking that by using angular material I dont have to worry about browser compatibility .

```
<md-input-container>
<input md-input type="date">
</md-input-container>
```

The output of both IE and chrome is present in the picture below highlighted in yellow.
[image]

Comment: The input type *date* is not supported by IE (see [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=input%20type%3D%22date%22)). You are using the native implementation with your code. Angular Material will provide us with an datepicker component but the work on that hasn't even started yet. You can take a look at the feature statuses [here](https://github.com/angular/material2#feature-status)

Comment: @benny_boe : Thanks I took this code from the same link which you posted it is written that md-input support it but no mention of browser compatibility so I assumed that it should work .

Comment: Well it is stated that you can use the listed input **types** with `md-input-container`. It might be a bit misleading that they actually refere to the native input types avaible in your browser at this point :) The "real" datepicker component might take a while to find its way into the Material package.. If you have to support IE right now, you should search of an alternative component or build one on your own

Answer (score 0):

Input type date is not supported by IE and Firfox as well ..

And as material 2 's datepicker has been not released yet .. you can take a look for mydatepicker or myrangedatepicker It is good with lots of features

https://github.com/kekeh/mydatepicker